# complexity for query?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If we are given a set of ranges `S={ (x1,y1) , (x2,y2) ,......(xk,yk) }` on an array of length n.Then I am given queries from set `Q={ (l1,r1) , ......(li,yi) }`. Each query (li,ri) means how many ranges from set S fall between this range (li,ri).
I just want to know whether following things are possible:

```
  1. Pre-computation in O(n) and then queries in O(1)
  2  Pre-computation in O(nlogn) and then queries in O(logn)
```

PS:I don't want the solution just the above two points, I want to come up with the solution on my own.

Comment: are the ranges in set S in sorted order i.e. either by first int or second int ?

Comment: yes you can assume they are sorted

Comment: Short answer to 1: yes, it's possible (at least assuming a finite number of possible values for your `x` and `y` values).

Comment: @JerryCoffin the sizes of set Q and S can be at max equal to n, is still the point 1 ?

Comment: Yes, assuming (for the sake of example) that all the x's and y's are integers 0..n, you can (at least theoretically) support constant-complexity lookup. The "theoretically" part would be: if `n` is too large, you may not be able to fit it all in memory.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The best I am able to come up is `O(logn)` complexity. What's the approach for `O(1)` time ? really curious to know this.

Comment: @SrikarAppal: Will depend on whether these are 1D or 2D ranges (both possible, but not clear which is intended).

Comment: @JerryCoffin since the ranges are in the format (x,y) I think they are meant to be x-y coordinates. meaning 2D ranges. in a 1D range, sure I know how to asymptotically guarantee `O(1)` but what's the deal with 2D ranges ?

Comment: @JerryCoffin as i said ranges are on an array of size n thus all ranges are l,r with 1<=l<=r<=n and thus are 1D ranges

Comment: @SrikarAppal: With 2D ranges, the same *basic* idea applies. You start with a 2D matrix. For each input range, you increment the appropriate spots in the matrix. Then you walk through that matrix, and generate each possible range, and add up the values in the matrix for that range. Index into that for a query.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks a lot I will really try to come up with the first solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here goes. Since I cannot just give a yes/no answer. I will elaborate slightly without spoiling the mystery for you.

> **Pre-computation in O(n) and then queries in O(1)**

Since you mentioned that the ranges in set S is sorted (lets say on end element). We could go ahead without any sort of precomputation. With just this I believe we can achieve a query time of `O(logn)` with the help of divide & conquer strategies. But Getting the query time of `O(1)` seems a bit far fetched. Even with the usage of [range trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) or [kd-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), the best you can expect is `O(log)` complexity. Maybe if we use some auxiliary data structures (like say a hashtable) along with the given sets we could try cook something up but still `O(1)` seems a bit ambitious. All this begs to be asked, what are your space requirements?

> **Pre-computation in O(nlogn) and then queries in O(logn)**

This definitely seems possible. You might not even need `O(nlogn)` for pre-computation since you say they are already sorted. Reg. query time, for each range in set Q it would take `O(logn)` time. So for k ranges in set Q it would take `k * O(logn)`. How big do you expect your set Q to be?